# Load view passing two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have two dropdownlist in one view but i don't know if i can load the view passing the two arrays like this:

```
$this->load->view('primerPaso',$data,$data2);
```

To be more specific i'm doing everything like this:

Model

```
/*
 * Método encargado de consultar las ciudades
 * donde existen agencias.
 */
function ConsultarCiudadesAgencias()
{
    $this->db->select('LISValor');
    $this->db->from('410LIS');
    $this->db->where('LISNombre','ESTLista3');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = array();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $result[$row['LISValor']] = $row['LISValor'];
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

/*
 * Método encargado de consultar los diferentes
 * tipos de vehiculos que existen para su alquiler.
 */
function ConsultarTiposVehiculos()
{
    $this->db->select('LISValor');
    $this->db->from('410LIS');
    $this->db->where('LISNombre','SUBLista3');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = array();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $result[$row['LISValor']] = $row['LISValor'];
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->model('PrimerPasoModel');
    $data['ciudades'] = $this->PrimerPasoModel->ConsultarCiudadesAgencias();
    $data2['vehiculos'] = $this->PrimerPasoModel->ConsultarTiposVehiculos();
    $this->load->view('primerPaso',$data,$data2);
}
```

and in the view i have this (not going to paste all the html):

```
<tr>
    <td>Ciudad de Alquiler:</td>
    <td><?php echo form_dropdown('CiudadAlquiler',$ciudades); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <?php echo form_dropdown('TipoVehiculo',$vehiculos);?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

whit this code i get this error:

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: vehiculos
>
> Filename: views/primerPaso.php
>
> Line Number: 76

Where "primerPaso.php" is the name of mi view.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the same `$data` array and it'll work.

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->model('PrimerPasoModel');
    $data['ciudades'] = $this->PrimerPasoModel->ConsultarCiudadesAgencias();
    $data['vehiculos'] = $this->PrimerPasoModel->ConsultarTiposVehiculos();
    $this->load->view('primerPaso', $data);
}
```